# Adding new column in dataframe by taking ratio of two existing columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new column in dataframe by taking a ratio of two existing columns. Following code works but it does not retain the column df[price_per_sqft].

`df['price_per_sqft'] = (df['SalePrice']/df['LotArea'])`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Please supply a [mcve]. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) if you need help with this.

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
df['price_per_sqft'] = df['SalePrice']/df['LotArea']
```

or you can use `pd.assign`

```
df.assign(price_per_sqft = df.SalePrice/df.LotArea)
```